# How can I mask an Image into a Layer?

Tags: coffeescript, framerjs

These are my first steps with FramerJS and I would like to know how to mask an Image into a different layer when I scale the image with an animation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
layer = new Layer width: 256, height: 256
layer.style =
  "-webkit-mask-image": "url(images/framer-icon.png)"
```

you can mask an image using "[-webkit-mask-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask-image)". this property is only worked in Webkit-based browser, but framer is also worked in Webkit-based.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the best way is to put the image inside a Framer layer and mask it with a parent Framer layer.